# How to sort fields and methods in source code documents?

Tags: coding-style, ide, code-formatting

In many programming languages, fields and methods can be arranged freely, but the order impacts the readabilty of the code. **Which ordering strategy do you apply?**

*Background: We (a group of researchers from the University of Trier) already looked at the code of different open source projects and tried to figure out what strategies are applied. But as you can imagine, it is hard to extract this information from the code. Now, we are interested in the concrete strategies you apply and want to share and discuss this information here. Please find further information on our [project page](http://www.st.uni-trier.de/icsm12/).*

Comment: Public methods first and the rest by order of appearance in these public/interface methods. As for fields - configuration fields on top; the rest grouped logically and in order of appearance.

Answer (score 1):

- private fields first
- public fields (if any)
- properties (if any, e.g. in C#) or simple Getter/Setter
- constructors
- public methods
- private methods near to their appearance in public methods (in functional programming languages even inside public methods if possible)

Moreover I try to order each of these sections semantically or to their importance for the class. I really try to structure my code so that I can quickly gain an overview of everything important. However in very big classes I have my problems to follow my strategy and then I often use the outliner to get to fields or methods instead of looking for them by scrolling.